# How Can I Draw an Arc in Android XML?

Tags: android, xml

I want to draw an arc as an Android XML object. I need it to be an xml, not a Drawable I can code programmatically (that'd be too easy!) because I need it for a notification icon.

I know how to code circles and rings, and I can use radius on rectangles to get quarter/half circles fine. However, I can't figure out how to code just any arc (e.g. 30 degrees) in an xml. Is it possible?

Comment: you cannot do that, xml drawables are not general ways for drawing anything: only the simple shapes are supported - if you need more complex drawing you have to do that in java - see `android.graphics.drawable.shapes.Shape` class

Answer (score 10):

that `XML` is still a `Drawable` resource, while `SVG` is being called `vector` & `path` in there. you can use whatever tool to create vector paths, which then can be used as the `pathData`. the correct location for such files is `src/main/res/drawable-nodpi`, here's one example `path` (and one can put several of them into such a `vector`):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<vector
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:viewportWidth="500.0"
    android:viewportHeight="500.0"
    android:width="50dp"
    android:height="50dp">

    <path
        android:fillColor="@color/colorAccent"
        android:pathData="M 250 250 A 100 100 0 0 0 450 250 Z"/>

</vector>
```

the actual know "how to draw an arc" (with the values of the above path):

[image: vector path construction]

meanwhile Android Studio even has a "Preview" tab for that:

[image: AS screenshot, XML preview]

Comment: Hi, I'm not that familiar with vectors. Wouldn't that cause it to not look smooth, since it'd just be lines from one point to another? Also, how then would you get an arc (hollow, like 1/8 of a ring) rather than a solid semi-circle or something?

Comment: @Elliptica does the preview in the screenshot above appear "not smooth"? if there's anything "not smooth", then these are raster-ized graphics, alike PNG, BMP, GIF, WEBP, when exceeding their default 100% zoom (their original size); while vector graphics scale perfectly at any size. this is called a `Bézier curve` (or tool), eg. in Photoshop, Illustrator, GIMP, InkScape. only rather old versions of Android need to have them (automatically) rendered to PNG, with the support library.

Comment: @Elliptica and most easy, eg. when having to create 1/8 slice, to use a design application to tweak the path, and then save to `SVG`, open again with a text editor and then paste that `path` into `pathData` (because Android Studio has a `Drawable` preview, but not a `Bézier` tool). a 1/8 slice would need one coordinate in the middle of the horizontal line and the outer two points located a tad lower, in order to fall into shape.

Comment: this is not an are but hemicycle

Answer (score 1):

For me, the solution was quite simple. I had to use Figma to create the Arc.

**Note: It does not matter whether or not you have prior experience with using Figma or any design tool for that matter. It is a very simple and straightforward process and it takes less than 5 minutes to achieve.**

---

Now, let's get to the good part...

- The first step is to [download the Figma Desktop app](https://www.figma.com/downloads/) and draw an arc. [This short video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oJCG6sl-Ecw) pretty much summarizes how to draw an arc.
- The second step is to export your arc as an SVG file. Again, this is a straightforward process, [this 51-second video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZouvuUCytt4) summarizes this process.
- The last step is to add the SVG file to Android studio. To do that, go to *File > New >Vector Asset* and then select *Local File* in the menu that pops up. All in all, you should see a menu like the one below. Note that the name of my SVG local file is arc.svg.

[image]

Comment: Hi Taslim. Just a quick note: there is no need to add "hope this helps", "merry coding" or other chatty material. _Stack Overflow_ is intended to be a curated collection of Q&A, and it is rather closer to documentation than a chat room. Please try to stick to technical writing if you can. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Arc is just like a **quarter-circle**. So, you need to draw rectangle shape to form an arc.
Below code is to draw an arc using rectangle shape :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
<size android:height="15dp" android:width="15dp"/>
<solid android:color="@color/darkGray"/>
<corners android:topRightRadius="0dp" android:bottomRightRadius="15dp"/>
</shape>
```

Comment: hi, that's actually the part I said I knew how to do. I can do quarter and half circles fine. But what if I wanted an 1/8 circle or something?

Comment: then you should use canvas to draw an arc. Below link will help you: http://android-coding.blogspot.com/2012/04/draw-arc-on-canvas-canvasdrawarc.html

Comment: Arc is not "just like a quarter circle". Arc is a curved line.