# How to draw shape like below image

Tags: java, android, design-patterns

Please help me to draw a shape like the image below. I have tried many things, but none of the code worked.

[image: Image of expected output, blue curve above grey]

This is what I have tried

```
 private Point mFirstCurveStartPoint = new Point();
 private Point mFirstCurveEndPoint = new Point();

 .................................................
 .................................................

      mFirstCurveStartPoint.set((mNavigationBarWidth / 2) - (CURVE_CIRCLE_RADIUS * 2) - (CURVE_CIRCLE_RADIUS / 3), 0);
    // the coordinates (x,y) of the end point after curve
      mFirstCurveEndPoint.set(mNavigationBarWidth / 2, CURVE_CIRCLE_RADIUS + (CURVE_CIRCLE_RADIUS / 4));

    mFirstCurveControlPoint1.set(mFirstCurveStartPoint.x + CURVE_CIRCLE_RADIUS + (CURVE_CIRCLE_RADIUS / 4), mFirstCurveStartPoint.y);
    // the coordinates (x,y)  of the 2nd control point on a cubic curve
    mFirstCurveControlPoint2.set(mFirstCurveEndPoint.x - (CURVE_CIRCLE_RADIUS * 2) + CURVE_CIRCLE_RADIUS, mFirstCurveEndPoint.y);

     mPath.reset();
    mPath.moveTo(0, 0);
    mPath.lineTo(mFirstCurveStartPoint.x, mFirstCurveStartPoint.y);

    mPath.cubicTo(mFirstCurveControlPoint1.x, mFirstCurveControlPoint1.y,
            mFirstCurveControlPoint2.x, mFirstCurveControlPoint2.y,
            mFirstCurveEndPoint.x, mFirstCurveEndPoint.y);
```

**is there any way to done this using Xml layout**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an image in svg format, use [Asset Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/vector-asset-studio) to convert it to xml drawable. Otherwise, use code like that:

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="500dp"
    android:height="300dp"
    android:viewportWidth="500"
    android:viewportHeight="300">
  <path
      android:pathData="M0,0h500v300h-500z"
      android:fillColor="#e3e3e3"/>
  <path
      android:pathData="M0,80C0,250 487,104 550,247L500,300L0,300"
      android:fillColor="#3e47cb"/>
</vector>
```

Answer (score 2):

Since I can't add comments because of low reputation, check this [link](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0261__2D-Graphics/0201__Curve.htm).

Adding another link if you're going to use Java [here](http://zetcode.com/gfx/java2d/shapesandfills/), in **Areas** section some great example how to achieve your shape using `setVisible`.

Comment: @Developer I've never tried to do it with xml, I have no experience, but I've found some examples: 
[example_for_shapes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41971893/how-to-create-a-custom-shape-for-a-button), 
[example_for_curving_edges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51959648/how-can-i-draw-an-arc-in-android-xml), give it a try. Edit: set the background to either blue or grey and choose the shape you want to create and fill it with collor.